# Will the iTunesArtwork.png image be overwritten by the App Icon in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

We just submitted a buid for review but realized we left the iTunesArtwork.png image in the root of the app in xCode. This was an old image that doesn't match the new icons, but we forgot to remove it. Will this be replaced by image we've uploaded under App Icon in iTunes Connect?

I know the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) says "Do not include" the iTunesArtwork image for the App Store, but we don't want to remove the version from review to upload a new build. Is this a problem? Should we remove it and resubmit with a new build without that image, or is it ok as it will be overwritten by the App Image in iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that will happen is that the app will be bigger than necessary. Remove it for your next build.